# Javascript with HTML if statement

Tags: javascript

I am currently using JavaScript with HTML to create a number input, and once a number is input, an option from a select list tells whether to double the number or not. I feel I have done everything correctly, however, when I run my code and select yes to double, the output number is the number input and does not double. I am assuming my `if` statement is incorrect but I am not sure, I am new to JavaScript. Appreciate any feedback.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <input id = 'number' name = '' value = '' class = ''>
    <select id = 'double' name = ''>
        <option value = 'Y'>YES</option>
        <option value = 'N'>NO</option>
    </select>
    <button id = 'go' class = ''>GO</button>
    <input id = 'result' name = '' value = '' class = ''>
    <script src = 'js/javascript 03.js'></script>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById('go').onclick = function () {
    var number = document.getElementById('number').value;
    var double = document.getElementById('double').value;
    number = parseFloat(number);

    if (double == 'Y') {
        number * 2;
    };

    document.getElementById('result').value = number;
};
```

Comment: `number * 2` does indeed double the number... but with no `=` in that line it doesn't get assigned to anything.

Comment: You need to reassign the variable `number`, use `number = number * 2;`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol but if i assign number = number*2 that defeats the purpose of choosing yes to double and no to keep the number the same. it just doubles it every time

Comment: Spaces between attributes, `=` and values is invalid html, i'm not quite sure that it will even render properly.

Comment: @Astonishing Nooooo... because you're doing that *inside* the `if(double == 'Y')` check...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`number * 2;` does not store the value anywhere. You should use one of the 2 cases here:

```
number *= 2;
number = number * 2;
```

Comment: but if i assign number = number*2 that defeats the purpose of choosing yes to double and no to keep the number the same. it just doubles it every time

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments to your question, doing just `number * 2` will evaluate to a value. But that value is not stored anywhere, so you need to put it back in its own variable:

```
number = number * 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int colCount=5;

    File fpath = new File("C:\\Users\\man.xls");
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(fpath);

    if (fpath.exists()) {
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
        int sCount =wb.getActiveSheetIndex();
        Sheet sh = wb.getSheetAt(sCount);

        int rwNum = sh.getLastRowNum();
        sh.createRow(rwNum+1);
        int rwNuafterr = sh.getLastRowNum();

        Row rw = sh.getRow(rwNuafterr);
        for (int j = 0; j <= colCount; j++) {
            rw.createCell(j);
            rw.getCell(j).setCellValue("char");
        }
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\man.xls");
        wb.write(outputStream);
    }
```